# Post_date is ignored when a post is published

Tags: wordpress

I'm inserting posts inside wordpress, and I get an extrange issue.

**Example array**

```
[
'post_title' => 'Hi there',
'post_content' => 'Hi there',
'post_date' => '2016-12-01 12:00:00',
'post_status' => 'publish'
]
```

When I enter to edit the post using wordpress editor, I see date is different that I filled up and replace with the actual date.

I want to keep my original `post_date` when I insert a post.

How can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Jaster

Comment: Please post more code. An array while helpful isn't enough to provide further guidance. How are you inserting posts? With `wp_insert_post()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get modified date using this function,

```
<?php get_the_modified_date( $d ); ?>
```

and display directly modidied then use this function

```
<?php the_modified_date( $d, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

for details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date

and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date

or you want publish date then use this function,

```
<?php the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

for details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

i hope it'll help you

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my problem is when I publish the post, my original post_date is overwrite and updates with the actual date. I want to keep my original date, when I publish a post.